# Derrière nos écrans de fumée

Tags: sens, expressions

Il y a une série sur Netflix sur les médias sociaux qui s'appelle *"Derrière nos écrans de fumée"*.

La seule traduction de fumée que je connais c'est la fumée d'une cigarette par exemple.

Mais quel est le rapport avec des écrans ? Je ne comprends pas.

Merci.

[image: Série Netflix Derrière nos écrans de fumée]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Écran de fumée

is using the word "écran" not to refer to a computer screen but rather a screen that blocks sight.  Literally, it would be best translated "smokescreen."  [Larousse.fr](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9cran/27712#:%7E:text=2.%C2%A0Tout%20ce%20qui%20arr%C3%AAte%20le%20regard%2C%20qui%20dissimule%2C%20emp%C3%AAche%20de%20voir%C2%A0%3A%20Un%20%C3%A9cran%20de%20fum%C3%A9e.) has one definition of "écran" as:

> Tout ce qui arrête le regard, qui dissimule, empêche de voir : Un écran de fumée.

The television series makes reference not to a literal smokescreen but rather a social smokescreen raised by which social media allows us to hide who we really are, hence the English title of the series "The Social Dilemma."

Comment: Are you sure that it's not a pun, and *écran* is being used to mean both computer screen and smokescreen? Social media very much happens on computer screens.

Comment: @PeterShor it could well be... though if that is the case, the pun isn't present in the English title, which is why I assumed that wasn't the main point. But quite probably that was part of the intention.

Comment: Puns are very difficult to translate. I suspect *écran de fumée* is used metaphorically in French in ways that make the pun work. English doesn't use *smokescreen* metaphorically the same way, so an English title *"Behind our smoke screens"* would baffle people.

Comment: @PeterShor They surely tried to do a pun because of the word **Derrière nos** IMO, as Écran de fumée is a [real expression](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cran_de_fum%C3%A9e) but adding those two words add a metaphor to the computer screen of everyone.